# No android device found in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, adb

When I am building a game for android, I get this message:

> No Android device found!
>   Make sure USB debugging has been enabled.
>   Check your device. In most cases there should be a small icon in the status bar telling you if the USB connection is available.
>   If you are sure that your device is attached then it might be your USB driver that's the problem. For details please check the Android SDK setup section in the Unity manual.

The cancel windows showed this error:

> No android device found! If you are sure that your device is attached then it might be your USB driver that's the problem. For details please check the Android SDK setup section in the Unity manual.

The same error also appeared in the Console.
How do I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: It should work if you do what I provided in my answer. What is your android device Model number?

Comment: you do not even state if you are using a Mac or PC

Comment: key is often to turn on **Debugging** on the android device

Answer (score 61):

Disconnect the USB cable from your android device, go to **Settings > Developer Options** and turn **off and on** the **USB Debugging** . Also tap on "Revoke USB Debugging Access". Now, connect the USB cable. When prompted tap "Yes".

If this doesn't help follow @Programmer answer.

Comment: how can a simple thing like this be the solution of big companies problems ?
damm.... a simple "restart" is the problem....

thank you for this answer... I really can't imagine a thing of this happening in 2018.... we really need to improve our developers lol

Answer (score 11):

**1**. Install the driver for Android device on your computer.

**2**. Enable DEBUGGING in your Android device.

For Unity to be able to detect your Android device, it must be recognizable by the ADB program.

Open command prompt with `cmd` the change your directory to `AndroidSDK\platform-tools` with `cd /d G:\AppDev\AndroidSDK\platform-tools`  .

Replace `G:\AppDev\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` with your android SDK location. then type `adb devices`. If no device is found then Unity wont' recognize it. Reboot your computer and try it again.

Once you see a device number, like in the picture below, then it will work in Unity.

[image]

Comment: make sure that when drivers are installed , your device will ask to make a connection with your pc so accept it , otherwise it wont work

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm facing an issue after uninstalling and reinstalling unity. Not sure what happened. I did try to switch from Scripting runtime version 3.5 to 4x but I reverted and still isn't working. I've been able to build the entire time until last night when I uninstalled and reinstalled. Here is my SO question. I'm at a total loss.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341936/how-to-solve-unity-no-compatible-android-device-found

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that you have **"Charge only"** in USB options - I had **MTP** enabled and the same error. After disabling MTP everything works fine.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 10):

For all those who spent hours trying to find out what's wrong and none of above answers helped. 
Please also check if cable you are using is not cheap "charging only and no data transfer type".

I've picked up a random cable from my cable box. After trying everything and loosing x amount of hair and time, I've decided to check a different cable, and voila everything worked immediately.

Answer (score 4):

To all  Huawei owners check that under network is actived USB tethering,then activate USB debugging. I was changing SDK,downloading all sorts of ADB and USB drivers. Breaking my head 2 days until i find in some webpage that Huawei requires that USB tethering is on.

Comment: Worked for me! I have an honor device so the setting was under the personal hotspot section and now my pc is connected via Ethernet instead of Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 3):

Changing a USB cable worked for me. 
Ironically, from an expensive fancy one to a super-simple cheap one.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. In my case, the usb driver was not installed by default with the AndroidSDK. I dunno why this is even optional, but it sure screwed me up.

Open Android Studio, click Configure->SDK Manager. In the center area, next to SDK Platforms, click the SDK Tools frame. Near the bottom is "Google USB Driver", which for me was unchecked and said Not Installed. Check the box and click Apply. It should download the usb driver. For me, it was put into C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

Now I can actually follow the almost-correct instructions found here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the device was working just fine, but once while unity was building up the editor froze and I had to kill the unity editor, and when I started it again unity couldn't recognize the device, and so after hours of struggling I finally find the solution.

first, identify the adb status of your device
go to the Android SDK path on your computer and under platform-tools open the `cdm`

and type the following

```
adb devices
```

for me, my device is there but its state is, unauthorized.
and so the solution was to authorize it again, there are many ways to do it:

1- try to switch the USB debugging option on and off under **Developer options/Debugging**
   also, try to Revoke USB debugging authorizations.

the goal is to make the "authorize this computer" popup appear to update the status.
however; this didn't work for me the popup didn't appear, the solution to forcing the popup to show is as follow:

2- go again to platform-tools and open the `cmd`

type

```
where adb
```

Identify all the duplicate entries in the path. Remove duplicates.

Now do

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
adb start-server
```

the popup should now appear, and the status of the device should be authorized.

credit to @user6123723

Answer (score 2):

I had Android Studio installed prior to Unity. My phone model showed up and I was able to run the app on the phone fine. In Unity project setting, the phone model did not show, just 'Any Android Device'.

That's a tell tale sign. Nothing was wrong with the system since the laptop could talk to phone with Android Studio. Something was not right with Unity.

So I checked Unity project preferences > External tools > Scroll down to "Android SDK Tools Installed with Unity (Recommended)" and changed the default value to the other SDK path on my system. Both of these seem to work:

- D:\Android\**Sdk** (where I installed with Android Studio)
- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\**sdk** (don't know where this came from)

They were of the same version 26.6.1 (checked by sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --version)

After the setting, I closed Unity, restarted adb, and check if phone was detected by

- **sdk**\platform-tools\adb kill-server
- **sdk**\platform-tools\adb start-server
- **sdk**\platform-tools\adb devices

I also made sure that when plugged in, the phone has USB Debugging ON (or allow USB debugging in charging mode, but not recommended) and the Camera (PTP) / Transfer photos / Photo Browsing via USB option is chosen.

When running Unity, the issue was resolved. Unity still does not show my phone name, but it is displaying game fine.

Hope this helps anyone passing by.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar problem via TCPIP - in my case adb from the command line was connected but unity (2019.4.18f1) on PC  couldn't find the device and in fact every time I refreshed the devices in UNITY it disconnected the TCP adb connection. Used your suggestion and switched from the UNITY built-in adb to android studios adb and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

if @Programmer or @kamran-bigdely solutions didn't work, then go to Edit > Project Settings > Editor, and change "Device" option to "Any Android Device".
Best of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it works for me

Check ARMv7

[image: Check ARMv7]

Unchek Android TV Compatibility

[image: Unchek Android TV Compatibility]

Answer (score 0):

Manually installing the drivers for your phone worked for me.

I did it through this link: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows. Even though it is a link from 2015, it worked perfectly fine with my Galaxy S8.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent 3 days before I've checked build settings and found that I'm building for PC, not Android. Check it in File > Build Settings...

If you don't see your device in Build Settings... > Android > Default device, try cmd solution described there: [No android device found in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825172/no-android-device-found-in-unity/43356832)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following to fix the issue.

1. Make sure USB debugging is enabled on the mobile device
2. Connect the device to computer and make sure you have granted permission / if already granted rewoke and redo the step
3. Try to Open device manager and look for your device and right click and update the drivers (if it din work you can search for specific driver from manufacturer's website)
4. Make sure you are connected to proper usb port (some drivers only support some usb standards)
5. Try to use the official cable from manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to fix my one.

1. I close my Unity. At my phone, I click Revoke USB Debugging Authorization and Ok to confirm.
2. Open Android Studio
3. Go to Tools | Connection Assistant. (Mine is V3.3.2)
4. Press Next, and there will be a page with "Restart ADB Server".
5. Then on my phone there is a dialog box asking to allow access from the PC.
6. Click Allow and that's it. Give a try to run an app from Android Studio.
7. If OK, then close Android Studio and reopen Unity and it should able to build and run on phone now.

source @ https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-device-is-not-responding.713705/

Answer (score 0):

Really silly but it fixed my issue (Windows 10 OS):

1. Win key -> Check for updates.
2. Install updates and restart.
3. Open Unity, go to "build setting".
4. Puff! Unity finds my device.

Answer (score 0):

Update 12 turned off usb debugging.